# Use "cout" like "Console.WriteLine" in C#

Tags: c++, printf, cout

Imagine there are many statement and messages to write out on the screen

```
cout << "statement A :" << a << "\t statement B :" << B
     << "\t statement C :" << C << "\t statement D :" << D;
```

in C# you’d write:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "statement A :{0}\t statement B :{1}\t statement C :{2}\t statement D :{3}",
    a, b, c, d);
```

it is like `printf` in C# but I don’t want to use C statements in my program; is there a way to write fewer `<<` in C++ without using `printf`?

Comment: In C# this is done by having `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` all derive from `System.Object`. In C++ it is done by overloading `operator<<` for the types involved. It's two different languages!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `boost::format` for example.

```
cout << boost::format("statement A: %1%\tstatement B: %2%\tstatement C: %3%\t statement D: %4%") %a %b %c %d << endl;
```

So in C# it was `Console.WriteLine("statement A: {0}\t...", a, b, c, d);`

Comment: You can also get rid of the `endl` (unless you really want to flush the stream but that’s generally not relevant).

Comment: Good but i don`t want to use "boost library"

Comment: @user1521362 You should embrace Boost. If you’re programming C++ then there’s no way you can write good code in big projects without using Boost.

Comment: @user1521362 write your own format.) if not - use printf or standard C++ output... C++ is not C#.)